# MongoDB 2.4 C++ driver - Undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file'

Tags: c++, mongodb, ubuntu, openssl, undefined-reference

I am trying to install the C++ MongoDB 2.4 driver using this tutorial:
http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-cpp-driver/

I downloaded and built the driver source code successfully using scons.

When I'm trying to compile the sample C++ file using the recommended command:

```
$ g++ tutorial.cpp -pthread -lmongoclient -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -lboost_system -o tutorial
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/libmongoclient.a(sock.o):
In function `mongo::SSLManager::setupPEM(std::string const&, std::string const&)':
(.text+0xc99): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/libmongoclient.a(sock.o):
In function `mongo::SSLManager::setupPEM(std::string const&, std::string const&)':
(.text+0xceb): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata'
```

I checked and I have already installed this packages: libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev.

Please help me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try compiling with crypto & ssl.

`g++ tutorial.cpp -pthread -lmongoclient \
 -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -lboost_system \
 -lssl -lcrypto -o tutorial`